# Number of two disjoint subsets from the an n-set $\{x_1, x_2,...,x_n\}$.

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can you select two disjoint subsets from the an n-set $\{x_1, x_2,...,x_n\}$?

Comment: @André Nicolas I think your solution is still of interest.

Comment: The special(?) case where these two subsets are both nonempty have that set as their union is described in [Terminology for splittings of a set into two parts](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1328913/terminology-for-splittings-of-a-set-into-two-parts).

Answer (score 5):

We are essentially partitioning our original set $X$ into three pieces: those in $A$, those in $B$, and those in neither set. Suppose $|A|=k$. How many ways are there to choose $B$? Of the $n-k$ items remaining, there are $2^{n-k}$ possible subsets to choose from. And there are ${n\choose k}$ ways to choose $A$ with $|A|=k$. So the total number of possibilities is

$$\frac12\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}2^{n-k}+\frac12,$$

where the factor $1/2$ accounts for the fact that except in the case $A=B=\emptyset$ swapping $A$ and $B$ amounts to the same choice (assuming that the two sets are not distinguished, it is not clear from your wording if this is the case).

Alternatively, as suggested by Qidi we can go elementwise, indicating for each element if it is in $A$, $B$ or neither, and this yields the answer $\frac123^n+\frac12$. So in fact this gives a combinatorial *proof* of $\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}2^{n-k}=3^n$ (which can also be derived by the binomial formula on $(1+2)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}1^k2^{n-k}$).

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  For each element, it can go in the first subset, the second subset, or neither.  You have counted a lot of things twice.....

Answer (score 1):

Assume there are $a_k$ ways to select two disjoint subsets from $\{x_1,\cdots ,x_k \}$, then consider the set $\{x_1,\cdots ,x_{k+1} \}$.

For each of the $a_k$ ways, there are $3$ possibilities for $x_{k+1}$: you can put it in the first subset, the second subset, or leave it out. Now when both subsets are the empty set, putting $x_{k+1}$ in either yields the same result, whereas in the other cases all $3$ possibilities are distinct. Hence $a_{k+1} = 3*a_{k}-1$.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment under the answers, but I came up to something similar to what @MarioCarneiro got, and instead of $+1/2$, I got $-1/2$ in the last part, so isn't it $(3^n-1)/2$ ?

**Update**
we can even check for a 2-set $\{1,2\}$, the disjoint subset pairs are
$$
\{1\} ; \{2\} \\
\{\emptyset\} ; \{1\} \\
\{\emptyset \} ; \{2\}  \\
\{\emptyset \} ; \{1,2\}
$$
Which are 4, $$
\frac{3^2-1}{2}=4
$$

Comment: You forgot $\emptyset:\emptyset$.

Comment: You're right, i did forget that. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Define a function $g(x)=1$ if $x$ belongs to $A$, $g(x)=2$ when $x$ belongs $B$ and $g(x)=0$ otherwise. Number of all combinations that can be formed using those $n$ words with their characters $0,1,2$ is $3^{n}$ . Thus, number of words that can be formed with ${1,0}$ are  due to empty $B$ is $2^{n}$. Similarly one can do it for $B$ due to empty $A$. Since the result is symmetric over $A$ and $B$ under pair ${0,2}$ due to empty $A$ it can form $2^{n}$ words again,   which is similar to count of ${0,1}$ as before. So, we have, $3^{n}-2^{n}-2^{n}+1$ disjoint pairs (Now $+1$ is there as we have a null word (all $0$)). Hence again to natural symmetry on any pair of $(A,B)$ word we have, $q_{n}=\frac{3^{n}+1}{2}-2^{n}$( If we ignore The fact of every subset with null pair is disjoint.).  Otherwise, $r_{n}=q_{n}+2^{n}=\frac{3^{n}+1}{2}$.

More Generally Simple applying Inclusion and Exlusion by considering $A$ and $B$ is disjoint in that famous formula one can get the below result that is ,
$|A|+|B|+2|C|=3^{n}-2^{n}-2^{n}+1=3^{n}-2^{n+1}+1$
Thus we have, $\frac{|A|+|B|+2|C|}{2}+2^{n}=\frac{3^{n}+1}{2}$. 
Otherwise readers must not fail to notice that we can also do it using recursion $a_{n+1}=3a_{n}-1$
One can Observe that $-1$ in the recursion part by Experimenting, How $a_{3}$ is going to generate from $a_{2}$